# CRTP with derived class overloading the method

Tags: c++, gcc, crtp

I just encountered a problem with the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), where I can't have the same method name (with a different signature) in both the base and derived class. The example to reproduce this issue is the following :

```
template <class T>
struct Base
{
    void foo(){}
    void bar(){
        static_cast<T*>(this)->foo(1,1);
    }
};

struct Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
    int foo(int a,int b){ return a+b;}
};

int test()
{
  Derived d;
  d.bar(); // works
  d.foo(1,1); // obviously works
  d.foo(); // compilation error
}
```

I tried this under various versions of GCC, clang and even ICC using [godbolt](http://goo.gl/sRJqRT)

Anybody could explain what is at work here ?

GCC output:

```
In function 'int test()':
22 : error: no matching function for call to 'Derived::foo()'
d.foo(); // doesn't work
^
13 : note: candidate: int Derived::foo(int, int)
int foo(int a,int b){ return a+b;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with CRTP, just that the `Derived::foo` *shadows* `Base::foo`, just as if you had declared a `foo` in an inner scope.

One way to un-shadow the `Base` version, is to <sup>[1]</sup>place a

```
using Base<Derived>::foo;
```

in `Derived`.

---

<sup><sup>[1]</sup> Full example at (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5dc7558e12babbe5).</sup>

Comment: I just saw that the CRTP indeed had nothing to play here, I didn't know that such shadowing did exist, thanks ! For reference see http://stackoverflow.com/a/411116/3781105

Comment: @Lectem: Johannes' answer there is good, but the selected-as-solution answer is not.

Comment: yeah I took the wrong link, but couldn't edit my comment anymore. If anybody needs to see what the standard says, here is Johannes' answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/411112/3781105