# How to call base class's function that is not defined in derived class?

Tags: c++

I always thought public methods of base class do get inherited by the derived class, even thought the derived class did not had definition of that particular method. For example

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


    class A {
    public:
        int f() { cout << 3; return 0;}
        int f(int x) {cout << x; return 0;}
    }; 

    class B: public A {
    public:
        int f() {std::cout << 5; return 0;}

    };


    int main(){
       B ob;
       ob.f(7); 

       return 0;
    }
```

I was expecting the result to be : 7 , but I get compilation error saying

" **error: too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 1; did you mean 'A::f'?**"

I know what the error is trying to say but I am little confused that the fuction from the Base class is not called.

Comment: overloading a function in derived class hides all base class versions

Comment: Use virtual keyword in A

Comment: I found a link from stackoverflow - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411103/function-with-same-name-but-different-signature-in-derived-class   which explains the question lucidly.

Answer (score 7):

Overloading a method in a derived class hides all base class versions.Even if the signature is different.If a method with the same name as in base class, exists in derived class then you won't be able to directly call base class versions.

You can do

```
  ob.A::f(7);
```

Answer (score 2):

With your posted code, `B::f` shadows all versions of `A::f`. You can call `A::f(int)` from an object of type `B` by using couple of methods.

1. Use `A::f` explicitly.

   ```
   B ob;
   ob.A::f(7);
   ```
2. Bring all versions of `A::f` into the scope of `B`.

   ```
   class B: public A {
      public:
         using A::f;
         int f() {std::cout << 5; return 0;}

   };
   ```

   Now you can use:

   ```
   B ob;
   ob.f(7);
   ```

Comment: @ R Sahu ,but the above case works in Java.

Comment: @a874, I am not familiar with Java. I can't comment on that. However, that has nothing to do with whether it works in C++.

Answer (score 2):

You can use another way:

```
class B: public A {
    public:
        using A::f;
        int f() {std::cout << 5; return 0;}

    };
```