# No matching function for to call

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance

I am new to Inheritance..

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class base
{ public:
    void show()
     {
       //do something here
         }  
    };

class derive:public base
{ public:
 void show(int n,int m)
    { 
      //do something
        }};


int main()
{
derive D;
  D.show();
  D.show(4,5);
    }
```

So the compiler is giving error that:
**no matching function for call to ‘derive::show()**

Comment: Please indent your code in one of the normal styles. This style is exceedingly difficult to read.

Comment: Just edited, to the simplest form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function with same name but different signature in derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411103/function-with-same-name-but-different-signature-in-derived-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the compiler processes

```
D.show();
```

it first checks whether the name `show` is present in `derive`. If it is, it does not look in the base class for the name. After that, it tries to find the best match for it. In this case, there is no match since the only function named `show` in `derive` expects two arguments of type `int`. Hence,

```
D.show();
```

is not valid.

If you want `base::show` to be available as an overload in `derive`, you have to let the compiler know.

```
class derive : public base
{
   public:

      // Let the functions named show from base be available
      // as function overloads.
      using base::show;

      void show(int n,int m)
      {
         cout<<"Derive Version.."<<n<<","<<m<<endl;
      }
};
```

Now, you can use:

```
int main()
{
   derive D;
   D.show();
   D.show(4,5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is correct. In the `derive` class there is no function`show()`. What I am guessing you want is to access the `base` class function however. To do this, you have to specify that it is the base class, not the derived class. To do this all you need to do is scope to the base class doing something like the following:

```
derive D;
D.base::show();       //Uses the bases function

D.derive::show(4,5);  // Uses the derived function
D.show(4,5);          // Uses the derived function
```

Comment: I always wondered if this resulting (necessary) syntax can be used for a good purpose if the classes are named nicely if it has template parameters. Like `D.fancy<5>::call()`.