# Question about the member functions whose names are same

Tags: c++, overloading

Why this [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/e8vPezWdh) does not compile if there is a member method named `Derived::foo(int)`,

```
#include <string>

class Base
{
public:
    int foo(int a, double b){return 0;}
    int foo(std::string a, double b){return 0;}
};

class Derived:public Base
{
public:
    int foo(int a){return 0;}

    int do_sth()
    {
        foo(2, 3.5);

        return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
}
```

,whereas the code [snippet works](https://godbolt.org/z/sKsezTfWG) below well when commenting out the said function.

```
#include <string>

class Base
{
public:
    int foo(int a, double b){return 0;}
    int foo(std::string a, double b){return 0;}
};

class Derived:public Base
{
public:
    //int foo(int a){return 0;}

    int do_sth()
    {
        foo(2, 3.5);

        return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
}
```

Here is what the compiler complains about the former code snippet:

```
<source>: In member function 'int Derived::do_sth()':
<source>:17:12: error: no matching function for call to 'Derived::foo(int, double)'
   17 |         foo(2, 3.5);
      |         ~~~^~~~~~~~
<source>:13:9: note: candidate: 'int Derived::foo(int)'
   13 |     int foo(int a){return 0;}
      |         ^~~
<source>:13:9: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

I think `foo(2, 3.5);` does exactly match the `Base::foo(int, double)`.It's amazing that the compiler complains about the former code snippet.

But since the compiler is almost always right, so I must miss something. Could somebody shed some light on this matter?

Comment: You should mark the function with `virtual`

Comment: @Autumnal_Joy, Uh, no that is not the issue here.

Comment: @Autumnal_Joy Mark the ***functions*** whose name is `foo` with `virtual`?

Comment: You've hit a nasty issue in C++. It does not have anything to do with virtual, but does relate to inheritance & overloaded functions. The member function in the derived class hides the same named overloads in the base class.  There is a solution I'm trying to double check - its been awhile since I've looked at this.

Comment: Adding `using Base::foo;` inside of Derived should prevent the other overloads from being hidden. I haven't found a good reference for this, but there should be a number around.

Comment: OK, there are multiple duplicate questions: [Why. .. hide other overloads...?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1628768/631266) and [Function with same name but different signature in derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/411103/631266)