# C++ method only visible when object cast to base class?

Tags: c++

It must be something specific in my code, which I can't post. But maybe someone can suggest possible causes.

Basically I have:

```
class CParent
{
 public:
  void doIt(int x);
};
class CChild : public CParent
{
 public:
  void doIt(int x,int y,int z);
};

CChild *pChild = ...
pChild->doIt(123); //FAILS compiler, no method found
CParent *pParent = pChild;
pParent->doIt(123); //works fine
```

How on earth?

EDIT: people are talking about shadowing/hiding. But the two versions of doIt have different numbers of parameters. Surely that can't confuse the compiler, overloads in child class which can't possibly be confused with the parent class version? Can it?

The compiler error I get is:
**error C2660: 'CChild::doIt' : function does not take 1 argument**

Comment: Wow. This is not much to go on...

Comment: I'm surprised you're seeing any methods at all.

Comment: basically I have... about nothing?

Comment: I think I can see your problem. You haven't written any actual code. I think you need to do that first before it'll work.

Comment: SO posted it before I finished. Give me 15s to fix it, for heaven's sake.

Comment: That code would fail because CChild isn't actually inheriting from CParent.  As for your actual problem, who knows?

Comment: Can't, hundreds of lines. Think of scenarios it could happen?

Comment: This reminds of several DailyWTF postings from back when DailyWTF was any good.

Comment: It's a dulicate. asked several times.

Comment: The above code isn't quite valid.  For starters, CChild isn't inheriting from CParent.  Does the parent class virtual keyword in the method.  Also different numbers of arguments... etc.. can you give a more fuller example?

Comment: for about the 9th time... they're SUPPOSED to have different numbers of arguments.

Comment: Answer to your edit: Yes, it can.

Comment: Shadowing is based solely on name, not at all on the types of the parameters.

Comment: And the reason for that is that in C++, name resolution happens as a separate step, before overload resolution. The compiler observes that there is a function in CChild that has the correct name, and it *stops looking*. Having chosen a context, it looks for an applicable overload in CChild, and doesn't find one, so reports an error. Why does it do that? Basically because the standard tells it to. It's not a logical necessity AFAIK, although I don't off-hand remember the motivation.

Comment: That's just plain crazy! I have no idea how I've used C++ for 10 years+ and never had this problem/

Comment: Well, if you cleverly don't use inheritance, then you avoid it ;-)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have shadowed a method. For example:

```
struct base
{
    void method(int);
    void method(float);
};

struct derived : base
{
    void method(int);
    // base::method(int) is not visible.
    // base::method(float) is not visible.
};
```

You can fix this with a `using` directive:

```
class derived : public base
{
    using base::method; // bring all of them in.

    void method(int);
    // base::method(int) is not visible.
    // base::method(float) is visible.
};
```

---

**Since you seem insistent about the number of parameters**, I'll address that. *That doesn't change anything.* Observe:

```
struct base
{
    void method(int){}
};

struct derived : base
{
    void method(int,int){}
    // method(int) is not visible.
};

struct derived_fixed : base
{
    using base::method;
    void method(int,int){}
};

int main(void)
{
    {
        derived d;

        d.method(1, 2); // will compile
        d.method(3); // will NOT compile
    }
    {
        derived_fixed d;

        d.method(1, 2); // will compile
        d.method(3); // will compile
    }
}
```

It will *still* be shadowed regardless of parameters or return types; it's simply the *name* that shadows. `using base::<x>;` will bring all of `base`'s "`<x>`" methods into visibility.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't think I'd still be discovering weird and whack C++ features.

Comment: The using directive will not bring all of the base class' methods into visibility.  Well, in this case yes, but in general.  It will bring all the methods with the name mentioned in the using directive into visibility.  It's nit-picky of me, yes.  But it's an important distinction.

Comment: For the first code snippet, `base::method(int)` is still not visible in the scope of `derived` even after the using declaration, because `derived` has a function with the same name and parameter types. (Notice this is a using *declaration*, not a using *directive* - the latter is the `using namespace ...` thing, which is unrelated).

Answer (score 3):

You are hitting a classic problem.  You need `using CParent::doIt;` in your CChild class.  I'll scrounge up the duplicate questions.

Edit:

Here's my answer to essentially the same question: [Overriding a Base's Overloaded Function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888235/overriding-a-bases-overloaded-function-in-c/888313#888313)

Comment: What? The overload in the child class has different parameters to the parent class. Why would it be a problem?

Comment: Read the linked answer. I think it will explain things.

Comment: All the examples posted are for overloads with same argument count. I can see those would confuse compiler. But when it sees doit(123), and finds doIt(x,y,z), why would it treat this as a match and stop looking?

Comment: No, it's a name match.  Once the name matches, it doesn't bother looking for other overloads higher in the hierarchy.  Just try `using` and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

I have never done this without having that method in the base class before.  I think that adding "using CLASS::METHOD" in derived class will give you access to the other version of the overloaded method.

```
class CParent
{
 public:
  void doIt(int x);
};
class CChild : public CParent
{
 public:
  void doIt(int x,int y,int z);

  using CParent::doIt;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `CChild` doesn't actually inherit from `CParent`.

And so it doesn't have a `doIt` method that takes only one argument.

Answer (score 0):

When you override a function in the derived class, only that function in the derived class is visible to the user of that class. The base class version becomes hidden.

Therefore, your pChild pointer calling doIt(int x) will fail since you are using a derived class pointer to call the base class function. The pParent pointer calling doIt(int x) will work since you are using a base class pointer to call the base class function. Even though you have a child object being pointed to by a parent pointer (upcasted), the class type here is determined by the declaration of the pointer which is a CParent.

To be able to call that base class function using the derived class pointer, you can:

1. Qualify the base class name in the function call, as in the following:

   `pChild->CParent::doIt(123);`
2. Use a using directive to bring the function name from the base class into the derived class, as seen in the previous posts.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this behavior is to give you flexibility to override the behavior of base class method in your derived class.

Lets assume that you have a function foo(int) in base class and you want to change the behavior of this function in your derived class. Now if the base class method is not hidden by your derived class method (which has same prototype as that of base class's method), it will introduce ambiguity in overload resolution.

Answer (score -2):

The method in your child class has a different number of arguments than what you're trying to pass into it. Could it be related to that?