# C++ Templates: Why does not this work?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ method only visible when object cast to base class?!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068088/c-method-only-visible-when-object-cast-to-base-class)

I've the follow code:

```
class String {
    char* _Text;
public:
    String( const char* s ) {
        int iLen = strlen(s);
        _Text = new char [iLen+1];
        strcpy( _Text, s );
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Vector {
public:
    int Add( T* pItem ) { return 0; }
    int Add( const T* pItem ) { return 0; }
    int Add( T& pItem ) { return 0; }
};

class StrVector : public Vector<String> {
public:
    int Add( char* pItem ) { return 0; }
    int Add( const char* pItem ) { return 0; }
};

void main() 
{
    String s;
    StrVector v;
    v.Add( s ); <-------------
}
```

The line `v.Add( s );` should call `Vector::Add(T& pItem)`, right?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068088/c-method-only-visible-when-object-cast-to-base-class

Comment: (1) `StrVector::Add` *shadows* `Vector::Add`; the lookup for `StrVector::Add` isn't going to look in the base class because it found the functions in the derived class. You can put `using Vector::Add;` in the definition to let them be found. (2) `String` needs to implement a destructor, which then entails you need [The Big Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29). (3) `Vector` either needs a virtual destructor or protected destructor; deleting through a base class pointer when it doesn't have a virtual destructor leads to UB. (4) `main` returns `int`!

Comment: (5) You should just be using `std::string` and `std::vector`. (6) You need to define "not work" when you ask questions: doesn't compile, doesn't do what you expect (and what did you expect) etc? Or I could have chosen any one of my points as an answer to 
"what's wrong".

Comment: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#overloadderived is another brief link to add to the pile, but I don't want to answer it as it is a duplicate.

Comment: GMan's comments should be converted to an answer & then accepted

Comment: Please, GMan, convert your comments to an answer so I can accept it. Thanx for all!

Answer (score 2):

The `Add` methods in the derived class [hide](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.9) the methods defined in the base class.

If you want the base class's `Add` to not be hidden, you can add a `using` directive to the derived class:

```
class StrVector : public Vector<String> {
public:
   using Vector<String>::Add;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope. You are hiding all the `Add` functions ov `Vector` by declaring `Add` functions in class `StrVector`. The compiler is issuing an error, and it is right: `int Add(String&)` is not accessible.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you mean by "not working" is that the call to `Add` doesn't compile (no appropriate candidate, or something similar).

The `Add` methods declared in StrVector hide the ones from its base class. See [Namespaces and the Interface Principle](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill08.htm) for a complete explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You never gave Vector an actual template argument, just said that it was a template. You need to have `template<typename T>`. Next, `StrVector` needs to inherit from `Vector<char*>`, although why you're inheriting from it I don't actually know.

Of cousre, in actual code, you'd use a `std::vector<std:string>`.

Comment: That was formatting error, I fixed it.

Comment: I think this is not the point.

Comment: @Alexandre: It was before the OP fixed his code.