# C++: inheriting overloaded non-virtual method and virtual method both with the same name causes problem

Tags: c++, overloading, method-signature, virtual-inheritance

I am trying to inherit two equally named methods with different parameter lists to a derived class. One of them is virtual and overridden in the derived class, the other one is non-virtual. Doing so, i get a compile error while trying to access the non-virtual method of the base class from an derived class object.

Here is the code snippet

```
class Base {
public: 
    void f() {
        cout << "[Base::f()]" << endl;
    }

    virtual void f(int arg) {
        cout << "[Base::f(" << arg << ")]" << endl;
    }
};


class Deriv : public Base {
public:
    virtual void f(int arg) {
        cout << "[Deriv::f(" << arg << ")]" << endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    Deriv d;
    d.f(-1);    
    d.f();  // <<-- compile error   
    return 0;
}
```

which produces the following compile error:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘Deriv::f()’
> note: candidates are: virtual void Deriv::f(int)

I am not an expert in C++, but until now I thought to be right in making the assumption that member methods can be completely distinguished by their signatures. Thus, the non-virtual method Base::f() should not be overridden and should remain accessible. Am I wrong with this?

Here are some interesting/additional comments on that:

  - the overriding method Deriv::f(int arg) could be non-virtual as well; 
  the error occurs in either way
  - the error disappears/can be circumvented...
    ... by casting the Deriv object to the Base class
    ... when not overriding Base::f(int arg) in Deriv
    ... by adding the command   "Base::f;"   to the public part of Deriv

So, since I already know how to avoid this compile error, I am mainly interested in **why** this error happens!

Comment: When you say "... by adding the command "Base::f;" to the public part of Deriv", you mean `using Base::f;`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding a Base's Overloaded Function in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888235/overriding-a-bases-overloaded-function-in-c)

Comment: @Tomaka17:
No, i mean exactly: put the line 
    Base::f;
to the class. But obviously this is the same as ths "using .." command.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `Deriv`, add this:

```
using Base::f;
```

In addition to the link given by @DumbCoder, you can find more details in my answer to a similar question: [Overriding a Base's Overloaded Function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888235/overriding-a-bases-overloaded-function-in-c/888313#888313)

Comment: yeah, i already know this (see my comments below the code snippet). but why do have to add this and what does this do?

Answer (score 2):

Derived class function hides the base function defintion. [Detailed explaination as to why](http://gotw.ca/gotw/005.htm) and [how](http://gotw.ca/gotw/030.htm)