# why I changed parent virtual function arguments in child hides the father function c++?

Tags: c++, class, virtual

I made a class with virtual function f() then in the derived class I rewrote it like the following f(int) why can't I access the base class function throw the child instance ?

```
class B{
public:
    B(){cout<<"B const, ";}
    virtual void vf2(){cout<<"b.Vf2, ";}


};
class C:public B{
public:
    C(){cout<<"C const, ";}
    void vf2(int){cout<<"c.Vf2, ";}
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    c.vf2();//error should be vf2(2)

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do `using B::vf2` so that the function is considered during name lookup. Otherwise as soon as the compiler finds a function name that matches while traversing the inheritance tree from child -> parent -> grand parent etc etc., the traversal stops.

```
class C:public B{
public:
    using B::vf2;
    C(){cout<<"C const, ";}
    void vf2(int){cout<<"c.Vf2, ";}
};
```

You are encountering **[name  hiding](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.9)**. Here is [an explanation of why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823287/c-inheritance-base-methods-hidden) it happens ?

Answer (score 1):

In C++, a derived class hides any base class member of the same name.   You can still access the base class member by explicitly qualifying it though:

```
int main()
{
    C c;
    c.B::vf2();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were caught by name hiding.

Name hiding creeps up everywhere in C++:

```
int a = 0

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::string a;
  for (int i = 0; i != argc; ++i) {
    a += argc[i];                    // okay, refers to std::string a; not int a;
    a += " ";
  }
}
```

And it also appears with Base and Derived classes.

The idea behind name hiding is **robustness** in the face of changes. If this didn't exist, in this particular case, then consider what would happen to:

```
class Base {
};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
  void foo(int i) {
    std::cout << i << "\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  Derived d;
  d.foo(1.0);
}
```

If I were to add a `foo` overload to `Base` that were a better match (ie, taking a `double` directly):

```
void Base::foo(double i) {
  sleep(i);
}
```

Now, instead of printing `1`, this program would sleep for 1 second!

This would be crazy right ? It would mean that anytime you wish to extend a base class, you need to look at all the derived classes and make sure you don't accidentally *steal* some method calls from them!!

To be able to extend a base class without ruining the derived classes, name hiding comes into play.

The `using` directive allows you to import the methods you truly need in your derived class and the rest are safely ignored. This is a white-listing approach.

Answer (score 0):

When you overload a member function in a base class with a version in the derived class the base class function is hidden. That is, you need to either explicitly qualify calls to the base class function or you need a using declaration to make the base class function visible via objects of the derived class:

```
struct base {
    void foo();
    void bar();
};
struct derived: base {
    void foo(int);
    using base::foo;
    void bar(int);
};
int main() {
    derived().foo();       // OK: using declaration was used
    derived().bar();       // ERROR: the base class version is hidden
    derived().base::bar(); // OK: ... but can be accessed if explicitly requested
}
```

The reason this is done is that it was considered confusing and/or dangerous when a member function is declared by a derived function but a potenially better match is selected from a base class (obviously, this only really applies to member functions with the same number of arguments). There is also a pitfall when the base class used to not have a certain member function: you don't want you program to suddenly call a different member function just because a member function is being added to the base class.

The main annoyance with hiding member functions from bases is when there is a set of public virtual functions and you only want to override one of them in a derived class. Although just adding the override doesn't change the interface using a pointer or a reference to the base class, the derived class can possibly not used in a natural way. The conventional work-around for this to have public, non-virtual overload which dispatch to protected virtual functions. The virtual member function in the various facets in the C++ standard library are an example of this technique.