# Cannot find baseclass function if baseclass has two functions of same name

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a baseclass that has two functions of same name but with different signatures in a 2-level inheritance.

```
struct A {
    virtual void f(int) { }
    virtual void f(int, int) { };
    virtual void f1(int) { }
};

struct B: public A { };

struct C: public B {
  void f(int, int) { }
  void f1(int) { }
};

int main() {
 C obj;
 obj.f1(0);
 obj.f(0,0);

 obj.f(0);    // (1) cannot be found
 obj.B::f(0); // (2) works

}
```

I would have expected my compiler (gcc-4.3.2) to find the correct definition at `(1)`, but I get

```
g++     main.cpp   -o main
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:20: error: no matching function for call to 'C::f(int)'
main.cpp:10: note: candidates are: virtual void C::f(int, int)
distcc[2200] ERROR: compile main.cpp on localhost failed
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

`(2)` on the other hand works.

What do I need to fix to make `(1)` work in general?

Comment: +1 for well-written post with complete example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write `using A::f` inside the definition of C.

You are a victim of name hiding! `void C::f(int, int)` hides `void A::f(int)`, just because.

Answer (score 5):

The C++ name lookup rules have it so that if a name is redefined in one scope, **all** overloads of that name are hidden.

But you can use `using` to help. Like this:

```
class A {
    public:
    int f(int x) { cout << "A::f 1\n"; }
    int f(int x, int y) { cout << "A::f 2\n"; }
};

class B : public A {
    public:
    using A::f;
    int f(int x) { cout << "B::f 1\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    B b;

    b.f(27, 34);

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
A::f 2
```

Answer (score 3):

The short answer to "why" is "because that's how overloading works."  You are hiding the `f(int)` overload in C.  The longer answer is much longer.

You can un-hide it by doing this:

```
struct C: public B {
  using A::f;
  void f(int, int) { }
  void f1(int) { }
};
```

Comment: Can you tell us the longer answer?

Comment: @honk:  Not right now, I'm short on time.  But I'll enlist some help with this.

Comment: It's not long, but here's an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888235/overriding-a-bases-overloaded-function-in-c/888337#888337

Comment: Thanks @Fred Larson, I should have found that.

Comment: @John: Never let answering get in the way of beer-o-clock, right? `:)`