# c++ virtual function problem

Tags: c++, inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Overriding a Base's Overloaded Function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888235/overriding-a-bases-overloaded-function-in-c)

I have a class like this one:

```
class Object {
public:
    int alignment() const;
    virtual void alignment(int i);
};
```

that I try to subclass like this:

```
class Sub : public Object {
public:
    virtual void alignment(int i);
};
```

then:

```
Sub *sub = new Sub();
sub->alignment(10);
int a = sub->alignment();
```

The compiler (clang 1.0) generates an error: "Too few arguments to function call, expected 1, have 0." I don't understand why the virtual function that takes an argument is getting confused with the non-virtual const one. Can someone please explain why?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888235/overriding-a-bases-overloaded-function-in-c/888313#888313

Comment: @Fred Larson that was just the explanation i was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Doing it like this *hides* the function overload in the base class.  Add the following to your `Sub` class to fix this:

```
using Object::alignment;
```

Comment: When doing this, I get an error about undefined references to vtable. See [here](http://ideone.com/XoqPN).

Comment: Is it allowed for an overloaded member function to be virtual ?

Comment: @Space: You need to define the functions

Answer (score 3):

Name lookup doesn't work the way you think it does.

The compiler starts at `Sub`, and looks to see if it has a function named `alignment`.  It does... so it stops looking.  It never even bothers looking at the parent classes, because it already found a match.  So the virtual override in `Sub` hides the non-virtual function in `Object`.  Unfortunately, that match requires an integral parameter, and you did not provide one.

Note that even if both `alignment` functions in `Object` were virtual, nothing would change.  By overriding one method, you hide all the other versions.

To fix it, provide a using declaration within `Sub` to bring the other function into scope, such that name lookup will find both versions.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the following makes the intention clearer:
`int a = sub->Object::alignment();`

Also you didn't specify the public keyword, as mentioned before by Space_C0wb0y

Comment: This is indeed another solution.  But I can't agree that this is clearer!

Answer (score -2):

int a = sub->alignment();

You didn't specify a parameter where it's expecting one.