# C++11 variadic template template parameters

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Keeping the old question. See below for resolution.
It is probably something simple, but still. I have the following C++11 code fragment:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename... Ts>
struct typelist
{
};

template <typename T>
struct EventContainer
{
    typedef T Type;
    /// TODO. Ring buffer
    std::vector<T> container;

    void push(const T& t)
    {
        EventContainer<T>::container.push_back(t);
    }

    virtual ~EventContainer()
    {
    }
};


template <template <typename...> class TL>
class EventStorage:
        public EventContainer<Ts>...
{

};

class Event1
{
};

class Event2
{
};

typedef typelist<Event1,Event2> Events12;

int main()
{
    EventStorage<Events12> ev;

    return 0;
}
```

How can I make `EventStorage` inherit `EventContainer` templeted with each of the types in the `typelist`. I could do it with Loki:: library, but I want to use C++11 with variadic templates. 
Thank you.

Resolution1: Fixing `EventStorage` template template issue. This will make `EventStorage`, multiple inherit all `EventContainer` templated with each type of `Ts`.

```
template <typename...>
class EventStorage
{
};

template <typename... Ts>
class EventStorage < typelist<Ts...> >:
        public EventContainer<Ts>...
{

};
```

Now I have compile time error, on the following `main()`:

```
int main()
{
    EventStorage<Events12> ev;
    Event1 ev1;
    ev.push(ev1);

    return 0;
}

In function ‘int main()’:
error: request for member ‘push’ is ambiguous
error: candidates are: void EventContainer<T>::push(const T&) [with T = Event2]
error: void EventContainer<T>::push(const T&) [with T = Event1]
```

Why the compiler is confused? After all I push with specific type.
GCC 4.6.1 here.

Resolution2:
As @Matthieu M. suggested I can present a forwarding method int `EventStorage`, but at a cost of one extra functin call:

```
template <typename T>
void push(const T& t)
{
    EventContainer<T>::push(t);
}
```

According to Alexandrescu, the compiler will optimize this forward call as long as parameters are references. 
Now the question is officially closed :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there any reason for introducing the `typelist` in the first place ?

```
template <typename T> struct Template { void push(T) {} };

template <typename... Args>
class Storage: public Template<Args>...
{
public:
  // forwarding...
  template <typename T>
  void push(T t) {
    Template<T>& me = *this;
    me.push(t);
  }
};

int main() {
  Storage< int, char > storage;
}
```

This [works](http://ideone.com/rOE53) and you can `typedef` the whole `Storage<...>` bit.

**EDIT**: Following on comments regarding the possibility to "combine" types.

There are two solutions:

```
template <typename...> struct CombineStorage;

template <typename... A, typename... B>
struct CombineStorage<Storage<A...>, Storage<B...>> {
  typedef Storage<A..., B...> type;
};
```

Or simply provide a typelist adapter:

```
template <typename... Args>
class Storage<typelist<Args...>>: public Storage<Args...> {};
```

Comment: I wish I could granulate different kinds of `Event` permutations. E.g.
`typedef typelist<Event1,Event2> pumpEvents;`
`typedef typelist<Event3,Event4,Event5> displayEvents;`
But as you put it that way, I would want to combine the two `typelists`, if the storage need to store them both.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a `typelist` adapter and a storage combinator.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try that, after I solve this ambiguity issue from my others answer comment. It is very strange. Isn't `push()` gots overloaded?

Comment: Overload resolution with inheritance doesn't seem completely intuitive: the solution in my answer works, but does feel ugly.

Comment: @DragomirIvanov: Exact, I needed to add a forwarding method to force the disambiguation. I didn't figure how to have a `using` directive (like @Useless) with a parameter pack expansion *on the outside*.

Comment: @Useless: Yes, it works :) Thank you very much. Any recommend paper to read why we actually need this ugly hack, appreciated. 
Thank you, guys.

Comment: Top answer here is the most concise answer I've found: essentially the compiler finds the first scope with one or more of overloads of the right name, and stops looking. Overload resolution, implicit conversions etc. are applied _only_ to this set of candidates. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72010/c-overload-resolution

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you're never even passing a typelist instantiation to the EventStorage, just the typelist *template*. So currently, there *is* no type pack to expand.

However, you should be able to unpack the typelist with a specialization and work with type packs otherwise:

```
template <typename...> class EventStorage;

template <typename Head, typename... Tail> class EventStorage<Head, Tail...>
  : public EventContainer<Head>, EventStorage<Tail...>
{
  using EventContainer<Head>::push;
  using EventStorage<Tail...>::push;
};

// allows you to pass typelists for convenience
template <typename... TL> class EventStorage<typelist<TL...>>
  : public EventStorage<TL...>
{
  using EventStorage<TL...>::push;
};
```

The `using` declarations just pull all the `push` methods into the same overload set, which seems to work for me.

The alternative would be to add a template method (maybe just to the toplevel typelist specialization) which explicitly forwards to `this->EventContainer<T>::push`, but it would require an exact type match.

Comment: Yes, I just figured it out myself. However I get ambiguity now.
Assume that added/replaced your fixes I get this:

`error: request for member ‘push’ is ambiguous`

`error: candidates are: void EventContainer<T>::push(const T&) [with T = Event2]`

`void EventContainer<T>::push(const T&) [with T = Event1]`

Main is:
`
int main()
{
 EventStorage<Events12> ev;
 Event1 ev1;
 ev.push(ev1);

 return 0;
}
`

Comment: Yeah, I didn't add the push bit, but it takes a little fiddling - editing now ...

Comment: Ah, now I see that there is a little misunderstanding.
I am wantihg to inherit every `EventContainer` each templated with each type in the `typelist`. My code is actually:

`
    template <typename... Ts>
    class EventStorage
    {
    };
    
    template <typename... Ts>
    class EventStorage < typelist<Ts...> >:
      public EventContainer<Ts>...
    {
    
    };
`

Edit: I just can't format sh*t here. I am sorry:(

Comment: Don't worry, the comments aren't ideal for lots of code :-)  Just edit it into the end of your question, and I'll take a look.