# Warning: overloaded virtual function "Base::process" is only partially overridden in class "derived"

Tags: c++, overriding, virtual-functions, name-hiding

I am getting below warning .
part of my code is :

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void process(int x) {;};
    virtual void process(int a,float b) {;};
protected:
    int pd;
    float pb;
};

class derived: public Base{
public:
    void process(int a,float b);
}

void derived::process(int a,float b){
    pd=a;
    pb=b;
    ....
}
```

I am getting below warning :

```
 Warning: overloaded virtual function "Base::process" is only partially overridden in class "derived"
```

any way i have made process as virtual function so I am expecting this warning should not come ...
What is the reason behind this ??

Comment: `virtual void Base::process(int x);` is hidden in `derived`. You may add `using Base::process` to solve that.

Answer (score 10):

The reason for the warning

```
Warning: overloaded virtual function "Base::process" is only partially overridden in class "derived"
```

is that you haven't overridden all signatures, you have done it for

```
virtual void process(int a,float b) {;}
```

but not for

```
virtual void process(int x) {;}
```

Additionally, when you don't override and don't use `using Base::process` to bring functions to scope the static calls to `derived::process(int)` won't even compile. This is because Derived has no `process(int)` at that case. So

```
Derived *pd = new Derived();
pd->process(0);
```

and

```
Derived d;
d.process(0);
```

won't compile.

Adding `using` declaration will fix this enabling for static call to hidden functions through pointer to Derived* and select operator d.process(int) to compile and for virtual dispatch (call to derived through base pointer or reference) to compile with no warnings.

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void process(int x) {qDebug() << "Base::p1 ";};
    virtual void process(int a,float b) {qDebug() << "Base::p2 ";}
protected:
    int pd;
    float pb;
};

class derived: public Base{
public:
    using Base::process;

    /* now you can override 0 functions, 1 of them, or both
    *  base version will be called for all process(s) 
    *  you haven't overloaded
    */
    void process(int x) {qDebug() << "Der::p1 ";}
    void process(int a,float b) {qDebug() << "Der::p2 ";}
};
```

now:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    derived d;
    Base& bref = d;
    bref.process(1);    // Der::p1
    bref.process(1,2);  // Der::p2 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you override a virtual method in a class, any overloads of that method that are not overridden are *hidden* for that class and cannot be used. So in your example, attempting to call `process(int)` on a `derived` object would fail because the overridden `process(int, float)` has hidden it.

Comment: "...are hidden for that class and cannot be used" Well, only when calling the function statically. You can always call it through a Base pointer / reference. I find it weird to call a virtual function in a static context, yet it makes sense sometimes. So I find it totally reasonable to only override one of the overloads...

Comment: @leemes Its certainly reasonable to only override one overload, but I can't imagine a situation in you would ever want this behavior. Personally I see it as a design flaw, but I might be missing some nuance of how overload resolution works or something. All I know for sure is working with OOP in C++ quickly makes me yearn for Java.

Answer (score 1):

You have only overriden one of the two overloads of `process`. You are missing the overload taking only an `int`.

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void process(int x) {;}; // You do *not* override this in derived
    virtual void process(int a,float b) {;}; // You do override this
// ...
};
```

Depending on what you want, you could:

1. Simply override the `int` overload too in `derived`; or
2. make the `int` overload nonvirtual and let it call the virtual `int, float` overload.

Two side notes: (a) Although most compilers accept it, a `;` after a function body is syntactically wrong. (b) Protected member variables are generally frowned upon nearly as much as public ones; you should use protected getters/setters and make the variables private.

Comment: I would avoid default parameter in virtual method.

Comment: @Jarod42: You're right. Now that you say it, I even remember that Scott Meyers has a whole item about the matter in Effective C++: "Never redefine an inherited functions default parameter value". So better use the last option.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a method with same name as one in `Base`, those methods are hidden.

It is the case when you override one method.

So

```
derived d;
d.process(42); // won't compile
```

To solve that: add `using Base::process`:

```
class derived: public Base {
public:
    using Base::process;
    void process(int a, float b);
};
```

As previous method don't silent the lint warning,
an other way to solve that is to override each method `process`:

```
class derived: public Base {
public:
    void process(x) { Base::process(x); }
    void process(int a, float b);
};
```

Comment: @Ashwin: So I see this warning as false positive... Btw `void process(int x) { Base::process(x); }` should silent the warning...

Comment: I have just created one dummy process function in derived class like below                                                                     void process(int x) {;}; ....It resolved my warning ...

Comment: @Ashwin: So you override it with same definition as `Base`, mine calls `Base` to be sure it is the same. The intend is clearer I think. I suggest to add comment to tell it is to silent lint warning anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[C++ overload resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72010/c-overload-resolution).

Long story short, partial overriding an overloaded function can be weird when trying to resolve the name.

Also, from a design standpoint. the pattern is generally odd. I have a function that I've decided is the same enough to warrant the same name: in general, it is a tacit agreement that it does the same thing. When you change the behavior of a function in the child class, then, it is weird if it you only change part of it in derived. Essentially, its easy to read (using ~= as about equal)

//IMPLICIT STATEMENTS

1) Base::process(int) ~= Base::process(int,float)

2) derived::process(int) ~= derived::process(int,float)

//EXPLICITE STATEMENTS

3) Base::process(int) == derived::process(int)

4) Base::process(int,float) != derived::process(int,float)

essentially, since 3 and 4 are in conflict, then 2 can't possibly be true.