# OpenCV warning: overloaded virtual function is only partially overridden

Tags: c++, opencv, warnings, header-files, jetson-xavier

So I am able to compile and execute this c++ program which uses OpenCV on Nvidia hardware.

```
#include <cudnn.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

cv::Mat ldimag(const char* image_path){
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread(image_path);
    image.convertTo(image, CV_32FC3);
    cv::normalize(image, image, 0, 1, cv::NORM_MINMAX);
    return image;
}

int main(void){
    cudnnHandle_t cudnn;
    cudnnCreate(&cudnn);
    cv::Mat image = ldimag("conure.jpg");
    return 0;
}
```

However i get the following OpenCV-related warnings when it compiles;

[image]

Environment:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Nvidia Jetson Xavier NX
- ARM64
- OpenCV 4.2.0

I do not want to ignore these warnings. Anybody understand this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are some other posts related to this topic with some responses

[Warning: overloaded virtual function "Base::process" is only partially overridden in class "derived"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21462908/warning-overloaded-virtual-function-baseprocess-is-only-partially-overridde/21463243)

[Warning: overloaded virtual function "Base::process" is only partially overridden in class "derived"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21462908/warning-overloaded-virtual-function-baseprocess-is-only-partially-overridde/21463038)